# can not curl port 80 on localhost

Tags: curl, port

when I do

```
curl localhost:80
```

it returns

> 404 Not Found

However, I can access port 8800 successfully:

```
curl localhost:8800
```

which returns a huge size of info...

Originally, port 80 was closed and not listened, so I have done

```
ufw allow 80/tcp
```

to open port 80,
then added

```
Listen 80
```

in

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and restarted apache2 to listen on port 80.

Now with

```
nmap -p 80 localhost
```

it shows

> PORT   STATE SERVICE
>
> 80/tcp open  http

and

```
netstat -lnp | grep 80
```

gives:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      980/mysqld
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9723/apache2
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8800            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9723/apache2
>
> udp6       0      0 fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:123 :::*                                1358/ntpd
>
> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8526     980/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9080     1316/master         public/flush

What else should I do to make localhost:80 reachable by curl?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I have disabled `iptables` as follows: `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`, `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`, `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`, `iptables -F`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem with the help from this page:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

As I found port 8800 were set as VirtualHost, in /etc/apache2/sites-available/, then I did the same for port 80. And Now with "curl localhost:80" I can fetch the webpage!